# confidence of face recognition using opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I tried to recognize faces using eugene face and Local Binary Pattern Histogram algorithms with OpenCV Python.The confidence level achieved with eugene face recognition was 2000,3000 etc. What should be the confidence level if the images were properly recognized ?

```
for image_path in image_paths:
 predict_image_pil = Image.open(image_path).convert('L')
 predict_image = np.array(predict_image_pil, 'uint8')
 faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(predict_image)
 for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
    nbr_predicted, conf = recognizer.predict(predict_image[y: y + h, x: x + w])
    nbr_actual = int(os.path.split(image_path)[1].split(".")[0].replace("subject", ""))
    if nbr_actual == nbr_predicted:
        print "{} is Correctly Recognized with confidence {}".format(nbr_actual, conf)
    else:
        print "{} is Incorrect Recognized as {}".format(nbr_actual,         nbr_predicted)
    cv2.imshow("Recognizing Face", predict_image[y: y + h, x: x + w])
```

Comment: Could you please give a minimal code example or link to the function you used?

Comment: @N.Perera you can refer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13652778/what-is-confidence-in-opencvs-facerecognizer

Comment: What is the exact meaning of "Confidence Value" and what range should be selected ?